# Error iterating through TR elements & building concatenated string values

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, concatenation, iterated-function

I am trying to write a javascript function that iterates through the rows of a table, picks up modified input values and builds a concatenated string of pipe delimited values onclick. Here is an example of the table which can vary in the number of rows ...

The result is no alertbox ... please can someone let me know why the alerts work in the each function but not outside that function and how to build these strings which ultimately will be passed via ajax.

The alert boxes work at the point of collection for each TR, however the concatenation and ultimately the alert outside of the each function does not work.

```js
function test() {
  //alert("The button was clicked.");

  var scf = '';
  var qtyf = '';
  var i = 1;
  var t = document.getElementById('my_id');

  $("#my_id tr").each(function() {
    var sc = $(t.rows[i].cells[0]).text(); //this works and returns the stockcode
    var qty = $(t.rows[i].cells[3]).find("input").val();

    //alert(sc);
    //alert(qty);

    scf = scf + '|' + sc;
    qtyf = qtyf + '|' + qty;
    i++;
  });

  alert(scf);
  alert(qtyf);
};
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column-code">Code</th>
      <th class="column-attribute">Colour</th>
      <th class="column-attribute">Size</th>
      <th class="column-qty">Qty</th>
      <th class="column-remove">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="product-queue-rows">
    <tr>
      <td class="product-sku">CZSPRBP32</td>
      <td><span class="swatch swatch-royal-blue"></span> <span class="swatch-title">Royal Blue</span></td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td><label class="fancy-quantity"><input type="number" class="product-quantity" value="1" data-sku="CZSPRBP32"><a href="#" class="fq-up" title="Increase"></a><a href="#" class="fq-down" title="Decrease"></a></label></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove-button" title="Remove item" aria-label="Remove item" data-sku="CZSPRBP32"><svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon class="svg-cross" points="17.744 20 12 14.256 6.256 20 4 17.744 9.744 12 4 6.256 6.256 4 12 9.744 17.744 4 20 6.256 14.256 12 20 17.744"></polygon></svg></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-sku">CZSPRBP34</td>
      <td><span class="swatch swatch-royal-blue"></span> <span class="swatch-title">Royal Blue</span></td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td><label class="fancy-quantity"><input type="number" class="product-quantity" value="1" data-sku="CZSPRBP34"><a href="#" class="fq-up" title="Increase"></a><a href="#" class="fq-down" title="Decrease"></a></label></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove-button" title="Remove item" aria-label="Remove item" data-sku="CZSPRBP34"><svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon class="svg-cross" points="17.744 20 12 14.256 6.256 20 4 17.744 9.744 12 4 6.256 6.256 4 12 9.744 17.744 4 20 6.256 14.256 12 20 17.744"></polygon></svg></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to call your `test` function. You're not currently

Comment: There's no element in the markup the selector `#my_id` could find, hence the loop is never entered. When get that fixed, you'll get an error, `i` should start from `0` instead of `1`. Notice, that the current index is passed to `each` callback as the first argument, you don't need to maintain the index manually. Now your task is to open the DevTools (hit F12) on your browser, there in the Console you can see how the script execution is stopped by an error, that's why you never see the final results.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually calling test and the selector is not targeting the rows.

jQuery can be used more efficiently. Since you have data-sku on everything, I suggest the following

```js
const $table = $('.product-queue-rows');
const $rows = $table.find("tr");
const getVals = () => {
  const result = $rows.map(function() {
    return { [$('.product-sku',this).text()] : $('.product-quantity',this).val() }
  }).get()
  //console.log(result);
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(result)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
}
$table.on('change', getVals);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column-code">Code</th>
      <th class="column-attribute">Colour</th>
      <th class="column-attribute">Size</th>
      <th class="column-qty">Qty</th>
      <th class="column-remove">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="product-queue-rows">
    <tr>
      <td class="product-sku">CZSPRBP32</td>
      <td><span class="swatch swatch-royal-blue"></span> <span class="swatch-title">Royal Blue</span></td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td><label class="fancy-quantity"><input type="number" class="product-quantity" value="1" data-sku="CZSPRBP32"><a href="#" class="fq-up" title="Increase"></a><a href="#" class="fq-down" title="Decrease"></a></label></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove-button" title="Remove item" aria-label="Remove item" data-sku="CZSPRBP32"><svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon class="svg-cross" points="17.744 20 12 14.256 6.256 20 4 17.744 9.744 12 4 6.256 6.256 4 12 9.744 17.744 4 20 6.256 14.256 12 20 17.744"></polygon></svg></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-sku">CZSPRBP34</td>
      <td><span class="swatch swatch-royal-blue"></span> <span class="swatch-title">Royal Blue</span></td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td><label class="fancy-quantity"><input type="number" class="product-quantity" value="1" data-sku="CZSPRBP34"><a href="#" class="fq-up" title="Increase"></a><a href="#" class="fq-down" title="Decrease"></a></label></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="remove-button" title="Remove item" aria-label="Remove item" data-sku="CZSPRBP34"><svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon class="svg-cross" points="17.744 20 12 14.256 6.256 20 4 17.744 9.744 12 4 6.256 6.256 4 12 9.744 17.744 4 20 6.256 14.256 12 20 17.744"></polygon></svg></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan for your solution. In my haste I forgot to include the "Add to Enquiry" button which calls the test function in the html. I see you are outputting the result array to the console log, please can you show me how you would write the javascript to pass the stockcodes and quantities to a processing script with ajax using a function called when the button is clicked. I will then be able to take it from there. Thank you so much.

Comment: I added the AJAX. You can change the `$table.on('change', getVals);` to `$('#send').on('click', getVals);` where you have `<input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />`